# Is the word 'getting' used as a gerund in 'getting stronger every day'?

Tags: gerunds, participles, ing

In the phrase, "Getting Stronger Every Day," I know that "getting" is a participle, but in this phrase, is it a gerund? If not, why?

Comment: It depends on the context in which you use it. As a reply to *What is he doing?,* I'd say it's a verb *(**He is** getting stronger)*. But as a reply to *What is his goal?* it looks more like a noun/gerund *(Getting stronger **is** his goal*) - where it pretty much *has* to be a noun in order to serve as the ***subject*** of the verb..

Comment: @FumbleFingers beat me to it!

Comment: @marcellothearcane: Only because I accidentally hit <return> before making the point about use as the ***subject*** of a verb! :)

Comment: @marcellothearcane Fumble Erm, kinda but not really. It's a verb in both instances. What you have correctly noted is that this clause has a different syntactic function in each case. In traditional grammar that would indeed make it a participle in the first example and a gerund in the second (although a verb in both). Many modern grammarians eschew the idea that gerunds and participles are of different PoS - instead viewing the one type of word a gerund-participle regardless of its grammatical function.

Comment: I changed *everyday*, which means *ordinary*, to *every day*, which means *daily*. It would also help if you edited your question to describe how you know it is a participle, and why you think it might be a gerund here.

Comment: @Araucaria That's interesting, thanks for the enlightenment! Would there be any way for the OP's phrase to be gerund? (if that's even possible nowadays) by the way, what's PoS? not sure you meant Point of Sale, as per google's suggestions!

Comment: There are people with the surname 'Getting'; the body-text version  "Getting Stronger Every Day" could be using a proper noun. Trying to dentify PoS's in non-sentences is often a mug's game.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's an interesting analysis, and I have no reason to disagree with it; however, by that logic, would something like *Singing more loudly every day* be a gerund? If you replaced it with another noun, it wouldn't really make much sense, e.g. *Song more loudly every day.*

Comment: @Dog: As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) says, *...although similar in usage to **verbal noun** ...  **gerund** retains properties of a verb while **verbal noun** does not; in English this is most evident in the fact that **a gerund can be modified by an adverb** and can take a direct object.* But I'll admit terminology isn't my strong suit. Consider *Reading carefully will help, Careful reading will help* and *Reading this book will help* (adverb, adjective, and direct object). I'd say they're all ***nouns** = "gerunds"*, but I'm not gonna argue if someone else knows better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for that. Perhaps it's worthy of another question?

Comment: @Dog: Personally I think the word (and precise *meaning*) of "gerund" is a fairly irrelevant throwback to the days when English was only analysed/taught in the context of ***Latin*** grammar, but I wouldn't normally closevote questions about such things.